# Add react snippets to lua neovim

Tags: javascript, reactjs, neovim

I use lua neovim configuration with  packer plugin manager. I added vim-vsnip plugin, wrote :VsnipOpen and added snippet list to plugin's file, but snippets doesn't work! How can i get snippets for nvim?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Without more details about your Neovim configuration, it will be impossible to help you. Have you also install and configure [Friendly Snippets](https://github.com/rafamadriz/friendly-snippets) with `vim-snip` plugin to add snippets for JS/React ?